# Java: "uses unchecked or unsafe operations. Recompile with..."

Tags: java, inner-classes, instanceof, comparable, nested-generics

Despite spending a significant amount of time googling for an answer to my predicament and re-reading the chapter on Generics in my Java textbook I cannot seem to fix the problems with the following code:

```
public class RedBlackTree<I extends Comparable>
{
    private int count = 0;
    private RedBlackNode root;

    private RedBlackNode current;
    private RedBlackNode[] stack;

    /**
     * Inner class used for representing the nodes of the red-black balanced binary search tree object.
     */
    private class RedBlackNode implements Comparable
    {
        private I id;
        private boolean is_btree;
        private RedBlackNode[] links;

        /**
         * Constructor for objects of the RedBlackNode class.
         * 
         * @param id The ID of the node.
         */
        private RedBlackNode(I id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                throw new NullPointerException("ID cannot be null.");
            }

            this.id = id;
            this.is_btree = true;
        }

        /**
         * Function for comparing the RedBlackNode object to another object.
         * 
         * @param obj The object to be compared.
         * @return If invocant > passed, returns 1; if invocant < passed, returns -1; if invocant = passed, returns 0.
         */
        private int compareTo(Object obj)
        {
            if (obj instanceof RedBlackTree.RedBlackNode)
            {
                RedBlackNode node = (RedBlackNode)obj;

                int result = id.compareTo(node.id);

                return result > 0 ? 1 : result < 0 ? -1 : 0;
            }
            else
            {
                throw new ClassCastException("Expected a RedBlackNode object.");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In particular, I'm receiving a popup with the following message:

```
Warnings from last compilation

C:\Users\...\RedBlackTree.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
```

Nearly every combination of I here or Comparable there still leads to such a popup.  I'm using the BlueJ environment for programming and this makes it impossible to incorporate the relevant compiler argument in order to see any details.

As far as I can discern from my research thus far, it's something to do with the fact that the inner class utilizes the I generic type and so the "RedBlackNode implements Comparable" and the compareTo method in the RedBlackNode inner class need to contend with that fact somehow.

I know that this question has been asked here on stackoverflow and elsewhere and answered many times, but I can't seem to apply what I've learned from those instances to my case.  I'm pretty new to Generics, so any help I can get here would be very much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make the following changes

```
public class RedBlackTree<I extends Comparable<I>>

private class RedBlackNode implements Comparable<RedBlackNode>

    @Override
    public int compareTo(RedBlackNode node)
            int result = id.compareTo(node.id);
            return result > 0 ? 1 : result < 0 ? -1 : 0;
```

In the compareTo remove type checking. Mind the public, therefore always use `@Override`.

Comment: Thank you!  Other answers certainly helped, but this answer fixed all of the problems (including noticing the public/private dilemma in overriding the compareTo function which I thought would probably cause an issue, but which no one else had yet mentioned).

Answer (score 2):

[Comparable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) takes a Type parameter. The compiler complains because you have not supplied it.

Comment: Yes, but even when I supply it with a type (such as <I> or <RedBlackNode>) I still run into various issues...

Comment: There are two places in your code that you're using Comparable without type information. Have you tried adding type information both places? It would be useful if you added examples on what you have tried.

Comment: When I type "class RedBlackNode implements Comparable<RedBlackNode>" I still receive the warning.  Also, is this "public class RedBlackTree<I extends Comparable<I>>" better for the outer class declaration?

Answer (score 2):

The warning is because you're using the raw type `Comparable` instead of giving it a type parameter. All you have to do is change the class definitions to

```
public class RedBlackTree<I extends Comparable<I>>
```

and

```
private class RedBlackNode implements Comparable<RedBlackNode>
```

and adjust the `compareTo()` method accordingly (which will actually simplify it considerably since you don't need the type checking and casting anymore).

Comment: Ok, that is actually what I have now (minus the "adjusting" of the compareTo() method).  How would you suggest I go about "adjusting" it?  Would this be appropriate: "private <RedBlackNode> int compareTo(RedBlackNode obj)"?  Right now (with that adjustment) I'm still receiving the warning and it points to "private class RedBlackNode implements Comparable<RedBlackNode>".